# j_spring_security_check - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Sending my login form is not working.
I get the message "The requested resource is not available", when sending the login form, which accesses /j_spring_security_check with the standard filter.

My application-servlet.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/inside**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />

    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
      users-by-username-query=
        "select email,password from users where username=?" />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">

    <intercept-url pattern="/resettingPassword.do**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resetPassword.do**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" invalidate-session="true" />
</http>
```

The spring-database.xml looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="daoImpl" class="com.afterguard.sailplanner.dao.DaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sailplanner" />
    <property name="username" value="sailplanner" />
    <property name="password" value="sailplanner2" />
</bean>
```

And my spring-security.xml like this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/inside**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />

    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
      users-by-username-query=
        "select email,password from users where username=?" />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">

    <intercept-url pattern="/resettingPassword.do**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resetPassword.do**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" invalidate-session="true" />
</http>
```

I have the following web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
            version="3.0">
  <display-name>SailPlanner</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>sailplanner</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sailplanner</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/users</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/create_event</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/save_event</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/403</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/sailplanner-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param> 

        <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My setup looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Show us the form where you login please. I'm fresh on Spring but I can tell you my working app doesn't have repeated form configs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing...

```
login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
```

in your `<form-login`

See the [Spring 3 -> 4 Migration Guide for XML](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login). The duplicate xml code also looks suspicious.